# A series number will be generated for each of the souvenir

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to make a series number that will be generated for each of the souvenir (in every column, different series number) For an example, series number for souvenir 1 will be "AK0001". I want "AK" to be permanently (cannot be changed) there. But otherwise for "0001". It can be changes randomly

I use laravel 5.4 and below, adminlte, heidisql

I only did add another rows for seriel number in every column of the souvenir

**SouvenirController.php**

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.souvenir.create');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $souvenir = new Souvenir;
        $souvenir->name = $request->name;
        $souvenir->dateReceived = $request->dateReceived;
        $souvenir->description = $request->description;
        $souvenir->receivedFrom = $request->receivedFrom;
        $souvenir->location = $request->location;
        $souvenir->status = $request->status;
        $souvenir->save();

        if( !$souvenir->save() ){
            return redirect()
                ->route('admin.souvenir.index')
                ->with('error', "Error creating souvenir");
        }
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.souvenir.index')
            ->with('success', "Souvenir created successfully!");     
    }
```

**souvenir_table_migration.php**

```
class CreateSouvenirTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('souvenir', function( Blueprint $table )
        {    
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('serNumber');
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->date('dateReceived');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('receivedFrom', 100);
            $table->string('location', 100);
            $table->string('status', 100);
        });
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-3">Series Number</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="serNumber" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
</div>
```

views - **index.blade.php**

```
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.souvenir.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Souvenir</a>
            </p>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Series Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($souvenir as $s)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $s->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->serNumber }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->dateReceived }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->location }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->status }}</td>  
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.souvenir.edit', $s->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Edit </a>
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.souvenir.show', $s->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> View </a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).parent().find('form').submit()" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</a>
                            <form action="{{ route('admin.souvenir.destroy', $s->id) }}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>

@endsection
```

Comment: the last four digit- do you want them to be number or any random string?

Comment: are you want a random number or series of a number like (1,2,3,4 etc)

Comment: @zahidhasanemon i want it to a number. In sequential order from 0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a random string after `AK` use `str_random` function to generate a random string.

```
$souvenir = new Souvenir;
$souvenir->serNumber = 'AK'.str_random(4);
$souvenir->name = $request->name;
$souvenir->dateReceived = $request->dateReceived;
$souvenir->description = $request->description;
$souvenir->receivedFrom = $request->receivedFrom;
$souvenir->location = $request->location;
$souvenir->status = $request->status;
$souvenir->save();
```

If you want a 4 digit number you have to use `str_pad`, `pow` and `rand` together to generate it so that you can use leading zero values like `0001`. If you just use `rand` you can't use leading zero values.

```
$souvenir = new Souvenir;
$souvenir->serNumber = 'AK'.str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, 4)-1), 4 , '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
//here 4 is the number of digits you want. you can change it according to your need
$souvenir->name = $request->name;
$souvenir->dateReceived = $request->dateReceived;
$souvenir->description = $request->description;
$souvenir->receivedFrom = $request->receivedFrom;
$souvenir->location = $request->location;
$souvenir->status = $request->status;
$souvenir->save();
```

If you want a sequential number use it like below

```
$max = Souvenir::latest()->first(); //assuming you are using created_at column

$souvenir = new Souvenir;
if($max){
    $souvenir->serNumber = 'AK'.str_pad(($max->id + 1), 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    //here 4 is the number of digits you want. you can change it according to your need
}
else {
    $souvenir->serNumber = 'AK'.str_pad((1), 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
$souvenir->name = $request->name;
$souvenir->dateReceived = $request->dateReceived;
$souvenir->description = $request->description;
$souvenir->receivedFrom = $request->receivedFrom;
$souvenir->location = $request->location;
$souvenir->status = $request->status;
$souvenir->save();
```

Comment: (2/2) QueryException 
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'AK6776' for column 'serNumber' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `souvenir` (`serNumber`, `name`, `dateReceived`, `description`, `receivedFrom`, `location`, `status`) values (AK6776, Water bottle, 2019-08-29, dd, Dasani Sdn Bhd, Faculty of Creative Multimedia, Active))

Comment: what is your column type for `serNumber` in database? It should be `varchar` type. not `integer` to put values like  `AK6776`.

Comment: Nope, just check the column type

Comment: thankyouuuu!!!! <3 I got it already. But, how about I want it to be in sequential order?

Comment: check i have added that part in the answer.

Comment: error I got

(2/2) QueryException 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `souvenir` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)

Comment: that means you don't have created_at column in database. you have to use $max = `Souvenir::latest('id')->first();`

Comment: It works but I got another problem. Whenever I delete one of the columns in the adminlte, the 'id' and 'serNumber' did not update the latest 'id' and 'serNumber'

Comment: delete button in **index.blade.php**

<a href="{{ route('admin.souvenir.show', $s->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> View </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).parent().find('form').submit()" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</a>
      <form action="{{ route('admin.souvenir.destroy', $s->id) }}" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      </form>

Comment: that's another problem. need to know how are you rendering your view.

Comment: edited header of my views - **index.blade.php** above

Comment: you are having problem only on delete? can you make sure it goes to the controller action or not.

Comment: Yes. Everytime I delete one of the rows, the <id> did not update. For example, I delete rows 3 which is <id> 3, <id> 4 did not change to <id> 3

Comment: well it don't work that way. if you delete id 3, id 4 won't become id 3. it will remain 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chnange last four dist please try to use

```
$fourdigitrandom = rand(1000,9999);
```

Then concat with AK

```
$string=  "AK" .$fourdigitrandom;
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_pad function for this.

e.g. : "AK".str_pad(($rowid + 1), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
output : AK000001

Here 6 is digit length
$rowid is your max('id') of your table row